# (Blazor) Individual Authentification in AZure

Tags: c#, azure, razor, deployment, blazor

I was reading a lot of tutorials, but they all seem to old and not updated anymore.

Situation: I got the **standard Razor-Project**  running(with **individual Authentification**). I deployed it. Website runs. But there seems to be something missing with the Login. Database connection configured, migration applied.

Now I am missing a steb by step tutorial to make that (standard) application work in **Azure** ?

[image]

Comment: What exactly you are looking? your question is not clear

Comment: How can I get authentification running with free tier of azure ?